# Linq query taking too long time to execute query than sql

Tags: c#, linq

We are moving our back end sql logic to front end and we are handling back end sql as Linq query in front end C#. It working fine but it take too long time to execute the query than sql. The below my code for your reference,

```
objTypeDefLst = (from t1 in objTypeDefLst
                                     join t2 in objTypeDefLst
                                         on t1.TypeDefid equals TUtil.CheckInt(t2.ParentId, 0)
                                     where t1.TypeDefGroup.ToUpper().Trim() == strTypeDefGrp.ToUpper().Trim()
                                     orderby (t1.TypeDefDesc == "Successful" && t1.TypeDefGroup == "ResponseType" ? 1 : 
                                     (t1.TypeDefDesc == "Failed" && t1.TypeDefGroup == "ResponseType" ? 2 : 
                                     (t1.TypeDefDesc == "Failed Attempt" && t1.TypeDefGroup == "ResponseType" ? 3 : 4)))
                                     select new TypeDefinition
                                     {
                                         ResponseTypeReason = (t1.TypeDefDesc + ":" + t2.TypeDefDesc),
                                         ResponseTypeCode = t1.TypeDefid + "~" + t2.TypeDefcode
                                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: What's `TUtil.CheckInt`? Why does it work if it's an entity framework query, is it? If it's not a EF-query you loaded all records into memory which is inefficient.

Comment: hi @Tim, Tutil.CheckInt is helper funtion to covert the object to integer.

Comment: So then the question remains why that works at all. Entity framework should not be able to convert this function to a SQL-query. So i'm thinking that this is actually a Linq-To-Objects query which explains why it's so slow. You are loading your database table into memory, into `objTypeDefLst` which seems to be a list. Instead you should use a pure Linq-To-Entities query without an intermediate list.

Comment: Table 'TypeDefinition' having more hit on database side. Also the table having 2000 rows only. So that we are planning memcached all the table records and and  retrieve it while needed by Linq in the above.

Comment: Ok, but then don't expect database performance. A database will always win when it comes to complex sorting and joins.

Comment: We are not using EntityFrameWork @Tim. using Ado.Net for db operations.

Comment: ok @Tim. You are saying no problem with above linq query right? The problem is project design right?

Comment: Yes, maybe there are smaller improves but i doubt that it will help much. Why you can't use the database(ADO.NET) to retrieve the records and then create the instances of TypeDefinition in your frontend code?

Comment: yes right now we are using ADO.Net approach only . But DB have more load by using this kind of Procedures. By reducing DB load we are trying this memcached and linq approach.

Comment: Hi @Tim , Thanks for your thoughts. The culprit is helper funtion "TUtil.CheckInt" .After alter that line with this Normal C# Convert.ToInt(obj) it is working faster. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After altering the helper function `TUtil.CheckInt(t2.ParentId, 0)` with `string.IsNullOrEmpty(t2.ParentId) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(t2.ParentId)`it is working faster.